# How to Query data from MySQL database after updating model field in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, model-view-controller

After updating posts model field in MySQL database using using Django framework, I'm unable to query posts from the Database. Whenever I run the command `python manage.py runserver`, all seems to be well with the server. However, when enter the post url to display the list of posts I uploaded on the database before updating the model field, I get `1054, "Uknown column 'start_post.author_id' in the 'field list'`
I have spent a couple of hours try to figure out why I'm getting the error but I still don't get it.
In model.py I had:

```
....
title = models.CharField()
preamble= models.Charfield()
body = models.TextField()
....
```

I updated the above model to:

```
....
title = models.CharField()
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
introduction = models.charfield()
body = models.TextField()
....
```

Before updating it everything was working appropriately. But after updating it I'm unable to access the list of posts on browser, from the url `start\` as well as the post detail page. I didn't have the author field in the first model but I added it to the updated model. What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: What you've provided isn't enough to give an answer. you need to provide views template and relevant details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After update models, you have to run the commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate
```

- makemigrations command will check the diffs between your current model in database and model in python code.
- migrate will really run the migration to reflect your model with database model.

You can find more information about makemigrations and migrate in [django documentation about makemigrations and migrate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/).

Comment: I ran both commands after updating it and the migration was successful